# Are there two ways to interpret in this example?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Can "I make a sandcastle on the beach" mean "I make a sandcastle sitting on the beach" and "I make a sandcastle and locate it on the beach"?

Comment: Note that it would be more  idiomatic to say "I am making a sandcastle on the beach" or "I made a sandcastle on the beach." English seldom uses the simple present tense to indicate a current or ongoing action, at least not in the way you did, which sounds foreign.

Comment: I'm not sure how those two meanings are different.  By the second one, do you mean "I make a sandcastle and then put it on the beach"?

Comment: Not the last one, because "locate it on" sounds like you moved it after making/building it (not recommended). Also *make* is incorrect, as @Robusto mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pragmatically, both you and the sandcastle are on the beach. I know this based on what I know about sandcastles. There is no real ambiguity in the sentence you wrote.

If you said "I made money on the phone" you would get a different pragmatic understanding, even though the structure is the same.  Meaning matters.